# Specifying thickness of lines in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

Is it possible to specify the thickness of lines (for edges and nodes) in Graphviz?

I've looked at the [documentation about attributes](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs), but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I'm surprised if it's not possible though.

Comment: Note that, while the ANSWER is a duplicate, the QUESTION is not. The referenced "duplicate" only asks how to change the width of edges. If I want to change the width of nodes, nothing about that question tells me that the answer is what I want. Also, googling graphviz node edge width doesn't find that answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Is [penwidth](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:penwidth) what you are looking for?

> Specifies the width of the pen, in points, used to draw lines and curves, including the boundaries of edges and clusters. The value is inherited by subclusters. It has no effect on text.